# Set Image as Background and Text on Top of it in qlabel

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qlabel

1. I have a PNG file with 45x45 ratio
2. I have Qlabel with 270x30 Pixel ratio

what I want is to insert PNG file as background and Text on it dynamilaclly.

Text length may change from large to small and vise versa, 
accorindly our image changes and fit the text inside the images its mean flexible image according to the text

```
QPixmap pixmapTarget = QPixmap(":/.png");
pixmapTarget = pixmapTarget.scaled(250, 27, Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio , Qt::SmoothTransformation);
ui->lable_1->setIcon(pixmapTarget);
```

but dont to insert text in the image and how to get flexible thing accoudning to the text.

Comment: Somehow if you set `border-image: url(:\path\to\picture);` in QSS, that makes the picture a background for most of widgets. Dirty hack that may do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

A QLabel can contain *either* a text *or* an image. Not both at same time. If you want to have an image as a background to a text, you will need to either use a QTextView and setup your text and background image as rich text, overlay two QLabel instances on top of each other with the image being the bottom one, or implement your own custom QWidget. The latter can be done in a variety of ways, including subclassing QLabel to in paintEvent first render the background image (see QPainter's documentation on how to draw a QImage or better, a QPixmap) and then call the base implementation of paintEvent to render the text.

Comment: Can you provide some example, how to do that. I have tried but did not get how to achieve that functionality.